# "Flattening" a Date Array returned by AJAX call to a String for use in DataTables 1.09

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization, datatables

I'm attempting to display a row in a data table with a bunch of date cells. The dates on the backend are represented as so:

`org.joda.time LocalDate closeDt;`

I'm making an AJAX call to GET a bunch of model objects that have multiple dates attached to them and feeding all of this data into a (legacy version 1.09) DataTable. The problem is, however, that closeDate is returned to me as an array of values that looks something like

[image: picture of ajax result]

Unfortunately, applying a serializer on the backend or doing any type of transformation of the model data or how it's being returned isn't an option due to the dependencies and issues around that migration.

I've tried the "mRender" function of DataTables like so:

```
{"mData": "closeDt", "sTitle": "Closed Date", "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
    var date = data[1] + "/" + data[2] + "/" + data[0];
    console.log("date is: ", date);
    return date;
  }},
```

But, even it hasn't been successful. Additionally, if I do identify a way to get "mRender" working I'd like to extract the function as there are five or six other dates that are being represented in the table in the same way.

How can I get the date array to be "compressed" into a single string, in "MM/dd/yyyy" format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up accomplishing what I needed by the following:

```
{"mData": "closeDt", "sTitle": "Closed Date", "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
    if(data !== null) {
      return new Date(data).toLocaleDateString({day: "2-digit", month: "2-digit"});
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }},
```

I had to put the if/else in because if the data was null for a particular record, the Date() was being set to 12/31/1969... I guess that's a default for something when you call new Date(), but I didn't spend much time researching why or how. I also had to copy/paste this in the "mRender" of every column that had a date and I'd like to research pulling it out to not be in violation of DRY, but for now it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You could [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring) the Date array:

```
var [year, month, day] = closeDt;
var dateStr = [month, day, year].join('/');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p0aty3rf/

Comment: Would this require looping through the object returned from ajax and changing all of the fields?

For example, the AJAX call is returning a "Document" that has:
DocumentId: String,
ClosedDate: Array,
FunDate: Array,
SadDate: Array,
ParticipantName: String,

And my ajax call is returning an array of these "Document" objects. So the real result looks more like:
Documents : [DocumentA, DocumentB, DocumentC]